# Fix error mysql server has gone away

Tags: mysql

My VPS very often fails to *"MySQL server has gone away (error 2006)"* and loses connection. I have increased the value of the variable in my.cnf but the condition did not improve. Here is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
default-storage-engine=myisam
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
old_passwords=1
skip-bdb
skip-innodb
max_allowed_packet = 256M
table_cache= 512M
wait_timeout = 180
max_connections = 2000
net_read_timeout= 180
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_limit = 512M
max_user_connections=300

[client] 
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
max_allowed_packet = 128M
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: you probably did but did you restart mysql?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue .. updated wait_timeout, max_allowed_packet, .... many settings ... nothing helped

Answer (score 5):

Increase your `wait_timeout` and `net_read_timeout` to something bigger than 180sec (3mins) like 3600sec if there are some queries that takes longer or if you are getting results sets that are really big. You may also want to increase `max_allowed_packet` to something bigger than 256M if your result sets are really big.